# display output of array

Tags: php, mysql

I used a plugin to input data into a database. Now I am displaying the data and writing code to search/sort. My problem is that I am not familiar with arrays that are put into a single field in a database. I’m not even sure of the correct “name” for data in this format. So if anyone could please direct me to a tutorial or documentation, I would appreciate it. Here is a sample of the code contained in one field of the database.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:32:"Green";i:1;s:26:"Red";i:2;s:31:"Blue";i:3;s:33:"Yellow";}
```

Ultimately I will need to display this data with a `<br/>` separating each element in the array. I also need to understand it better so I can search the fields that are displayed this way. I also really want to learn about it, because I believe it is fairly common and I should understand it.

Comment: Can you post a link to the plugin that made this and send another sample line?

Answer (score 3):

this data has been [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) so call

```
$array = unserialize($data);
print_r($array);
```

another popular encoding is JSON which you should also look into.

just so you know what is going on

- "a:4" says what follows will be an array with 4 elements
- "i:0" says this is the 0th index in the array
- "s:32" says what comes next is a string
- "Green" is that string
- the rest just follows this pattern

Answer (score 1):

That data has been [`serialized`](http://php.net/serialize). [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize) it to get the array back.